# Accessing a Jenkins plugin package from a Groovy script

Tags: groovy, jenkins

How can I find the path to a Jenkins plugin if I want to use it from a groovy script?

For example, just testing on the master, I'd like to be able to use the LabelParameterValue class from the NodeLabelParameter plugin. An example of what I'm looking for is below, (though it doesn't work).

`currentParameters.add(new hudson.plugins.nodelabelparameter.LabelParameterValue(nodeName))`

Comment: I was able to do what you are doing both from Jenkins Groovy console and Groovy system script running via Groovy Plugin. I used a class in Claim Plugin. So: (1) How are you running you Groovy script (2) Is the plugin loaded?

Comment: I discovered that this works in the Jenkins console, and it probably works in system scripts, but it doesn't work in the Groovy Postbuild (likely because it's not running on the master Jenkins). I guess the question now is how I can access the master via a Groovy Postbuild script.

`import org.jvnet.jenkins.plugins.nodelabelparameter.LabelParameterValue` (taken from the package name on Github)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Postbuild Groovy script you can specify *Additional groovy classpath*. For example: `/var/jenkins/plugins/claim/WEB-INF/classes` for Claim plugin code. I tried it and it worked.

Unfortunately the path has to be absolute and does not allow for environment variables (such as `${JENKINS_HOME}`). Also, I am not entirely sure where the script will look when run on a slave - on the slave or on master.

Comment: That worked great. Thanks! For anyone looking for this plugin specifically, it was in `/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/nodelabelparameter/WEB-INF/classes`, where `/var/lib/jenkins/` should be replaced with your hardcoded Jenkins home.  

I should also mention that I found a workaround to this issue, which is to use an "Execute system Groovy script" build step. You can access the current build using:  
`def thr = Thread.currentThread();  
def build = thr?.executable` and still import packages without classpath. (credit: http://bit.ly/K6G3OS)